# Apple TestFlight iOS Crash Data

Tags: xcode6, crash-reports, testflight, ios8.3

I have been testing my App via Apple's Test Flight. I was getting crash data until I needed to recreate my project from scratch due to a problem I couldn't resolve. Ever since, I do not see any versions beyond 1.14 in the Organizer Crashes panel. Even though the current beta is at 1.18.

[image]

Testers have reported that subsequent versions have crashed, but no data? The App ID is identical to the original App.

I tried logging with Apple, but they just credited my support call back again with no answer.

Any ideas on what is happening?

Thanks